# static method on child class with parametrized type

Tags: java

I have a Parent and a Child class:

Parent.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Parent {

  private final String name;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public Parent(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  static Parent create() {
    return new Parent("Parent");
  }

  static List<Parent> createList() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Parent("Father"), new Parent("Mother"));
  }
}
```

Child.Java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Child extends Parent {

  public Child(String name) {
    super(name);
  }

  static Child create() {
    return new Child("Child");
  }

  static List<Child> createList() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Child("Brother"), new Child("Sister"));
  }
}
```

I get a "The return type is incompatible with Parent.createList() Java(67109268)", but in this case `List<Parent> Parent.createList()` is static, and so is `List<Child> Child.createList()` and the create() methods works as I would expect.

Changing method names or return types would solve this issue, but I'm interested in why this is happening with static non abstract class methods, have researched on forums, but haven't found a solution.

In case anyone wonders, the way around this is the same as in instance methods:

Parent:

```
  static List<? extends Parent> createList() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Parent("father"), new Parent("mother"));
  }
```

Child:

```
  static List<? extends Child> createList() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Child("son"), new Child("daughter"));
  }
```

Grandchild:

```
  static List<? extends GrandChild> createList() {
    return Arrays.asList(new GrandChild("grandson"), new GrandChild("granddaughter"));
  }
```

Usage:

```
    {
      List<? extends Child> childList = Child.createList();
      childList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    {
      List<Child> childList = new ArrayList<>();
      childList.addAll(Child.createList());
      childList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: While return types are covariant, generics are invariant, but you can use bounding to specify a covariant (`List<? extends Parent>`) or contravariant (`List<? super Parent>`) generic type. That said, be mindful of PECS (producer extends, consumer super): you'd want the `?super` syntax for a class which _accepts_ those generic types, and the `?extends` for a class that _produces_ those generic types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be long but I'll explain :)

First of all, [in JLS, section 8.4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#:%7E:text=RuntimeException(%2290%20mph%3F!%22)%3B%20%7D%0A%7D-,8.4.8.%C2%A0Inheritance%2C%20Overriding%2C%20and%20Hiding,-A%20class%20C), the following is specified:

> A class C inherits from its direct superclass all concrete methods m (both static and instance) of the superclass for which all of the following are true:

Therefore, your method `calculateList()` is actually overridden by the `Child`. That's right - the `static` method is inherited from `Parent` although it is bound to a class but not to an instance.

Thus, because you inherit it, by redeclaring it you actually override it (This is also stated in JLS). So you have to retain the signature **and the return type** ([Which is not part of the signature btw](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)).

Finally, you changed the return type from `List<Parent>` to `List<Child>`, but because in Java [generics are invariant](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1516/ConceptsPL/variancetypo.pdf), `List<Child>` **is NOT** a subtype of `List<Parent>`. Therefore, you break the return type, thus you get the error.

So, by changing the name of the `static` method in `Child`, you no longer override an inherited `calculateList()`, therefore you do not cause any clash.

Hope it helped, have a nice day.

Comment: I believe in special [JLS 8.4.8.4. Inheriting Methods with Override-Equivalent Signatures](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.4): "**One of the inherited methods must be return-type-substitutable for every other inherited method; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs. (The throws clauses do not cause errors in this case.)**" (original emphasis)

Answer (score 1):

Generics are invariant *by default*, but you can change that per signature.

**invariant** means, only the type is acceptable, not any super- or subtype of it.

This is in contrast to **covariant**. Standard java is covariant - a subtype is acceptable anywhere. For a trivial example:

```
Integer i = 5;
Number n = i;
```

is perfectly legal java code. This is covariance: an Integer (a subtype of Number) is acceptable anywhere a Number is needed. In generics, this does not work:

```
List<Integer> listOfI = List.of(5);
List<Number> listOfN = listOfI; // nope, compiler error
```

It's invariant because it has to be. After all, this is, of course, totally legal and has to be because basic java is covariant:

```
listOfN.add(someDoubleValue);
```

However, if that previous snippet (`listOfN = listOfI`) was legal, we just.. added a double to a list of integers, whoooops.

The solution is simple. You want to **opt in** to covariance. That's done with `extends`. Update your `calculateList` method in parent to:

```
static List<? extends Parent> calculateList() {
  return List.of(...);
}
```

`List<? extends Parent>` means:

This is a list of.. I don't actually know what the list is restricted to (hence, the question mark: That stands for "I do not know"). However, I do know that, whatever it is, it's either `Parent`, or some subtype of Parent. Hence, if you call `.get(idx)` on this list, that expression is of type `Parent`. But, `.add()`? You can't call that, at all. You can only do things to a `List<? extends Parent>` that would be fine for **all** possible variants (so, fine for `List<Parent>`, fine `List<Child>`, fine for `List<GrandChild>`, and fine for `List<SecondChild>`. Trivially, nothing you can pass as argument to `.add(x)` fits that bill, other than the `null` literal, which indeed, you can do, but that's academic/pointless).

A few notes:

- `Arrays.asList` bad. Use `List.of` (asList is neither fully mutable nor fully immutable; the worst of both worlds. Do not use it).
- `static` methods that you also override is weird. Perhaps you want a factory instead.

Comment: My understanding of the question was that the OP didn't think static functions would override those of a superclass, so why does it matter what type they return? That seems a reasonable expectation: after all, static methods don't take part in polymorphism, so why should they override?

Comment: correct, I expected a child method to hide the parent method, not override it... the example is synthetic, real life application is a bit more complex, Arrays.asList is just an array wrapped in a list so an Array with extra poking bits... fixed size, mutable elements so exactly as it says on the tin.

Comment: overridden static methods happen all the time, that's a usual way of getting new object instances like <class>.createInstance()

Comment: Yes, static methods don't "do" inheritance, nevertheless, java-the-lang-spec erroneously think they do and applies things like `final` and the rules about overriding and what that means for return types to it. Hence, you can either [A] adhere to the rules, even if they don't accomplish anything, or [B] name your method differently to avoid the issue that the java lang spec is merely imagining exists here.